# Setting up a Subprocess In my Views.py -- Django

Tags: django, django-views, subprocess

I have a variable `symbol` that I am trying to pass into a python script called earnings.py in a script folder inside the app. The output will be a matplotlib graph. Is subprocess the best way to do this? If so, how would I do this? The documentation for subprocesses is confusing.

This is my best effort:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from tickersymbols.forms import SymbolForm
import subprocess
from backtests.scripts import earnings

def index(request):

    if 'symbol' in request.GET:
        symbol = request.GET.get('symbol','Invalid Symbol')
        request.session['symbol'] = symbol
    else:
        symbol = request.session['symbol']


    process = subprocess.run(["earnings.py", "symbol"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    process.communicate(stdout)


    return render(request, 'backtests/earnings.html', {'symbol' : symbol})
```

Comment: Can you put some of your code?

Comment: @Masoud I added my best shot. Thanks

Comment: What is the `earnings.py`? If you want to pass your variable as an argument for your script `earnings.py` you should use `subprocess.run(["python earnings.py", "symbol"]...`.